# AWS Cognito NotAuthorizedException: Invalid login token. Token signature invali

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Trying to integrate my code with AWS Cognito for authentication. I am able to get the token as well from my browser url after successful login using hosted UI authentication. But still I am getting the below error

```
NotAuthorizedException: Invalid login token. Token signature invalid. My parameters look fine to me

 AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
            IdentityPoolId: 'us-east-1:87*********',
            Logins: {
                   'cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_******': idtoken
            }
        });

AWS.config.credentials.get(function(err) {
            if (err) console.log("AWS Credential Error Call" + err);
            else console.log("AWS Credentials get function" + AWS.config.credentials);
        });
```

Any recommendations on how to debug it??

Comment: Are you able to decode the token you got at jwt.io?

Comment: Yes @Max Ivanov , I am able to decode token at jwt.io. I am getting following fields in the payload. Essentially, not seeing in jwt token after decoding error there.

Comment: { "at_hash": "****************",
  "sub": "54*****************",
  "email_verified": true,
  "iss": "https://cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_********",
  "phone_number_verified": true,
  "cognito:username": "*********",
  "aud": "no9***********",
  "token_use": "id",
  "auth_time": 1586554823,
  "phone_number": "+4479*********",
  "exp": 15**************,
  "iat": 15***********,
  "email": "my email address"
}˚

Comment: I was able to resolve this issue. It was an issue with AWS Cognito Identity pool settings where I need select "Choose roles from token" for "Authenticated role selection" section. All works fine!

.